# how request is sent from app to smart contracts?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

I don't understand the smart contract very well. when I deploy a smart contract on the blockchain, the smart contract is then saved on every node. does that mean that when a node try to contact the smart contract it contacts it on it's device ?
I am asking this because when I started solidity programming I didn't know what is meant by the sender address. Is it the address of the node (ip address) or what ?

forgive me If I don't understand it. It's the blockchain and It's kinda new.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right the contract when uploaded to the blockchain is distributed by every node.

However, requests to a contract are sent from wallets or other contracts, so the sender address is the address of the wallet or contract.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: is wallet the same as app ? for example android app ?

Comment: @ahmednader When I say wallet here I mean the wallet hosted on the blockchains. Apps like that just communicate with the wallet, they do the same thing but are different